# PerformanceResourceTiming.responseStart and PerformanceResourceTiming.requestStart both are 0 for a status ok http request

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, fetch-api, resource-timing-api

I want to measure TTFB (Time to First Byte) for an HTTP request. I've hosted a 0KB pdf file on an amazon S3 server, and I'm using the `fetch` api to get it. Here's my code:

```
let url = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/speedtest.waveform.com/ping.pdf";
await fetch(url).then(res => res.text());
let perf  = performance.getEntriesByName(url).pop();
console.log("ttfb", perf.responseStart - perf.requestStart);
```

In the chrome developers network tab, I can see the request and all of its timing info:

[image]

But I can't access this info in the `PerformanceResourceTiming` document. In fact, many of the attributes including `requestStart` and `responseStart` are unset. Printing the `perf` record to console shows:

[image]

This is weird cuz doing the same thing using this url works just fine: `"https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?bytes=0"`

Comment: I've added an issue for this to chromium bug tracking: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1133336#c3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was because [timing-allow-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Timing-Allow-Origin) header was not set by the s3 server. Cloudflare did set that option which is why I was able to read `ttfb` values.